# How to access the raw time-series dataset of GOES X-Ray Flux?

Tags: python, solar-flare, raw-data, flux

I would like to access the time-series dataset of X-Ray Flux obtained by GOES. I expect that the flux units to be Watts / square-meter; this is because of the figure below (obtained from [this Nature paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41597-020-0548-x)).

[image]

I first tried accessing the [GOES-R dataset](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/stp/satellite/goes-r.html), which contains netcdf (aka .nc) files. I followed the steps in [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360469/read-nc-netcdf-files-using-python) but was unable to open any of the netcdf files.

I also tried accessing the flux dataset from [NOAA SWPC](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/goes-x-ray-flux); I clicked the "data" tab and click the "json" link, but this only contains data from the last week or so. I prefer to have the full dataset spanning a few decades. The same site hosts an FTP link; the text files present here have data fields for "year", "month", and "day", but not "hour", "minute", and "second".

I notice that most of the data products available are fluxes averaged over a time-interval; I prefer the raw time-series if possible.

I am hopeful that a representation of this dataset exists in the form of a text-file (such as [this one provided by RHESSI](https://hesperia.gsfc.nasa.gov/hessidata/dbase/hessi_flare_list.txt)). Regardless, I am not sure how to access this dataset. I wonder if the data I am seeking is in the netcdf files that I am unable to open, or if there is another way to do this - perhaps with astroquery or astropy?

TLDR: I am looking for the GOES dataset containing the time-series (containing year, month, day, hour, minute, and second) of flux (measured as Watts / square-meter). How can I access this raw data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SunPy](https://sunpy.org), check the [Retrieving and analyzing GOES X-Ray Sensor (XRS) data](https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/generated/gallery/time_series/goes_xrs_example.html) example. There it explains how to download data with a time range and if wanted selecting the GOES satellite number.

If you would like the raw data in csv format, then you can get it from the [official archive for GOES data](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/stp/satellite/goes/dataaccess.html). There you can find full an average data in csv format up to March 4th, 2020 (it stops then because [GOES 16 and later are part of GOES-R](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/stp/satellite/goes-r.html)). The link looks like this:

`https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/YYYY/MM/goesXX/csv/gXX_xrs_2s_YYYYMMDD_YYYYMMDD.csv`

Where `XX` is the satellite number. For example, [this is the 2s cadence csv file from goes 15 for March 4th, 2021](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/stp/satellite/goes-r.html).

For GOES-R I don't believe there's a CSV archive, but [SunPy](https://sunpy.org) can [query and download it, as shown in the example on the gallery](https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/generated/gallery/time_series/goes_xrs_example.html).

Once you donwload the file with SunPy, you can [load, plot, manipulate, and convert that timeseries to any other format](https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/guide/data_types/timeseries.html) that [astropy tables support](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/io.html#supported-formats) (including csv).

This is an example on how to query the data and convert it into csv. This is only for one day, but you could extended to a different time range if wanted.

```
from sunpy import timeseries as ts
from sunpy.net import Fido
from sunpy.net import attrs as a

tstart = "2020-06-21 01:00"
tend = "2020-06-21 23:00"
result = Fido.search(a.Time(tstart, tend), a.Instrument("XRS"), a.goes.SatelliteNumber(16))
goes_16_files = Fido.fetch(result)
goes_16 = ts.TimeSeries(goes_16_files, concat=True)
goes_table = goes_16.to_table()
goes_table.write('goes_16_20200621.csv', format='csv')
```

Comment: The code snippet works as is for an old version of sunpy (one point something). Since updating to sunpy 3.0.1, `tstart` and `tend` are required to be datetime objects (as opposed to string representations). But, both old and updated versions are throwing the same error when changing the time range.

Using [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GOES_satellites) as a source for GOES-16 (and adding `import datetime` at the top of the code), I define `tstart = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 15, 23, 59)` and `tend = datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 21, 23)`.

Comment: The error that is raised is shown below:

`goes_table = goes_16.to_table()`
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_table'`

I wonder if this is related to recent issues on their [github](https://github.com/sunpy/sunpy/issues/5661). Any idea how to circumvent this? Ideally, I'd like the full dataset from each GOES satellite.

Comment: I think this is more of a stackoverflow question than an astronomy question. I have reformulated the question here - if you have the time, please take a look.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834781/changing-parameters-in-sunpy-tutorial-throws-an-error-is-this-a-bug

Comment: Yes, as it's being pointed in stackoverflow, my example was only for one day, which is only a single file (I should have mentioned it!). Glad you found the answer ;)